# Change text of "You must be logged in to checkout."

Tags: woocommerce

hii somebody please tell me how can i change woocommerce default text message "You must be logged in to checkout." at checkout page with my own text message "you have to login or register to join contests"

thanks in advance...

i am waiting here for a handsome reply/.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the code below.

```
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message( $var ) { 
        return 'You have to login or register to join contests'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', 10, 1 );
```

Code goes in your functions.php of your current child theme.

Comment: Hi, how we can add html tags into this content?

Comment: Hi @MitrovicSrdjan , have you tried adding the HTML as part of the string? Perhaps it will just render fine.